# Why doesn't scrapy xpath function support the 'matches()' syntax?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm running scrapy 0.20.2.

```
$ scrapy shell "http://newyork.craigslist.org/ata/"
```

I would like to make the list of all links to advertisements pages set apart the index.html

```
$ sel.xpath('//a[contains(@href,html)]')
... 
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"html")]' data=u'<a href="/mnh/atq/4243973984.html">Wicke'>,
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"html")]' data=u'<a href="/mnh/atd/4257230057.html" class'>,
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"html")]' data=u'<a href="/mnh/atd/4257230057.html">Recla'>,
<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href,"html")]' data=u'<a href="/ata/index100.html" class="butt'>]
```

I would like to use the XPath `matches()` function to match links the form of the regex `[0-9]+.html`.

```
$ sel.xpath('//a[matches(@href,"[0-9]+.html")]')
...
ValueError: Invalid XPath: //a[matches(@href,"[0-9]+.html")]
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`matches` is an XPath 2.0 function, and scrapy only supports XPath 1.0 (which does not have any regular expression support built in).  You'll have to extract *all* the links using a scrapy selector and then do the regex filtering at the Python level rather than within the XPath.

Answer (score 3):

For this special use case, there is an XPath 1.0-workaround using `translate(...)`:

```
//a[
  translate(substring-before(@href, '.html'), '0123456789', '') = ''
  and @href != '.html'
  and substring-after(@href, '.html') = '']
```

The `translate(...)` call removes all digits from the name part before the `.html` extension. The second line check makes sure `.html` is excluded (nothing before the dot), the last makes sure `.html` actually is the file extension.