# How to use matches function in xpath to extract an English word

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I'm a total newbie to `scrapy` and `python`. How can I extract an English word with `xpath`?

Here is a snippet of the `HTML` page:

```
<span title="vacant">
vacant
</span>


<span title="linen">
linen
</span>
```

How can I extract the English word of the `<span tile>` field

I've tried like this `selector.xpath("//span[matches(@title, '\w+')]/text()").extract()`. But I always got a syntax error for above sentence.

Can anyone guide me to the right way ?

**Update 1:**

I've install `lxml` package for python, so `matches` function here is valid I think. By the way, I've used `contains` function by `xpath` which is working good.

This is how I use `contains` function:

```
selector.xpath("//span[contains(@title,'.')]/text()").extract()
```

**Update 2:**

Actually I was scraping a English-Chinese dictionary, firstly, I'd like to extract an English word(*a random word*) which HTML source code is listed above, secondly, I'd like to extract the Chinese paraphrase correspond to the English word which HTML source code is like:

```
<span title="adj. [Chinese paraphrase of vacant]" style="display:block;">
adj. [Chinese paraphrase of vacant]
</span>
```

I use the `contains` function listed above to extract the Chinese paraphrase which is working great to me.

But how can I deal with the `matches` function to extract an English word.

Do I make my goals clear?

**Update 3:**

The page I scrape is [here](http://word.iciba.com/?action=words&class=15&course=1), please view source of this page

**Update 4:**

The error message of my `matches` function in `xpath` is like:

```
>>> sel.xpath("//span[matches(@title, '\w')]/text()").extract()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 90, in     xpath
raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % query)
ValueError: Invalid XPath: //span[matches(@title, '\w')]/text()
```

Comment: That exception is "unregistered function" maybe? Note it's *always* good to include the full error... not just *I always got a synattax error for above sentence* - that doesn't help anyone diagnose what the issue could be. What's the end goal - to extract only spans with single word titles or... ?

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, I didn't include the error messages. Since I think this maybe a easy question. Actually there is only one English word in the field <span title="[the_word]">the_word</span> if the 'title' is equal to an valid English word then the text of the <span> field is my desire word. The end goal is to extract the desire word. Anyway, I shall update my question tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: You will need a word list with english words to match them and a really long XPath expression. What the code tells me, is that you want to match text with only alphanumberical characters. You might want to reformulate your question.

Comment: @JonClements You were right, `matches` function is not supported in `xpath 1.0`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
words = selector.xpath('//ul[@id="word_list_1"]/li')
for w in words:
    word_english = w.xpath('./div[@class="word_main_list_w"]/span/@title').extract()
    word_chinese = w.xpath('./div[@class="word_main_list_s"]/span/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this would work in my case. My question is to figure out why 'matches' function isn't working in the first place.  Now after some research, it seems that the version of  'xpath' in 'scrapy' is 1.0 in which 'matches' function is not supported. So, I have to deal with it in python level instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920609/scrapy-and-xpath-function-matches-syntax). I'm using `scrapy 0.22.2` which only support `xpath 1.0`, you can refer to [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) in which `matches` function is not supported. So I have to deal with this case at python level. In order to extract all valid English words, I have to:

```
wordList = []

def isAllAlpha(s):
    format = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    for c in s:
        if not c in format:
            return False

    return True

def initWordList()
    for i in \
        sel.xpath("//span[not(contains(@title, '.'))]/text()").extract():
            temp = i.strip().lstrip('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t')
                            .rstrip('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t')
            if isAllAlpha(temp):
                wordList.append(temp)
```

This maybe stupid, but I can't find a better way so far.

Comment: A couple of notes: `temp=i.strip()` is all you need... that'll remove all whitespace from both ends... if you only wanted a subset (not including space for instance), then `temp = i.strip('\r\n\t')` is sufficient...

Comment: Your `isAllAlpha` seems unnecessary, Python has a builtin for strings that will deal with it: `if 'Alan'.isalpha():` or `if '123'.isalpha()` for instance - that should help tidy your code up a little bit anyway

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the notes, `strip('\r\n\t')` is working great. But `isaplha` is not working in my case, since I have to deal with some Chinese Word(in `unicode` form), as you know `unicode` object has no attribute `isaplha`.

Comment: Rolling all into one: `items = xpath("//span[not(contains(@title, '.'))]/text()").extract(); return [item for item in items if re.match('[a-z]$', item.strip('\t\n\r')]`

Comment: could you please answer this question, and explain your codes a little bit, I don't really understand this line `return [item for item in items if re.match('[a-z]$', item.strip('\t\n\r')]`. As a python newbie, the line `return[...]` is strange to me, return a ... ? And what's `re` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to this myself but I've been doing a fair amount of research for using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) and I think I can help clarify some of the posted code:

`return [item for item in items if re.match('[a-z]$', item.strip('\t\n\r')]`

The `re` in `re.match` is shorthand for regular expression RegEx), which is why it is followed by a regular expression to match: `[a-z]$` (that essentially means any letter of the english alphabet--any letter from a through z).

I'm most familiar with RegEx for Apache where `$` indicates the end of the string but I'm not sure here, it looks more like it's being used as a wildcard.

`items.strip` is saying "items to remove" and are RegEx for whitespace (in ASCII, I think...I'm not certain but I know it's related to the encoding of the document and how it's parsed and matched by RegEx).

`\n` is a 'new line.'

I'm going to guess that `\t` is 'tab,' and and I think `\r` is 'return' (or perhaps it's 'space')

That rule is likely to make sure that Unix style line endings (of the source files) `\n` and Windows style line endings, which I think are `\n\r`

So if explained I think that code is effectively saying...

"Produce 1 item for each of the items in an array that matches the following criteria: they contain any english letter from ***a*** to ***z***  and ignore the characters for 'new line', 'tab', and 'return'"

I also suspect the `i` in `i.strip` is shorthand for 'insensitive to case' meaning match both uppercase and lowercase letters.