# How to i can generate list from p tag ?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Please check the site :

```
https://www.americanberkshire.com/california.html
```

there are all in p tag

i wanna separating with each element but i can found effective way

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class AmericanberkshireSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'americanberkshire'
    allowed_domains = ['americanberkshire.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.americanberkshire.com/california.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        lists=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for red_paragraph in response.xpath('//p[re:test(text(), "\([A-Z]{3,}\)")]'):
        paragraphs = [red_paragraph]
        for paragraph in red_paragraph.xpath('./following-sibling::p'):
            if not paragraph.xpath('string(.)').extract_first().strip():
                break
            paragraphs.append(paragraph)
        # In each iteration reaching here, paragraphs will contain a list of
        # related paragraphs.
```

Comment: i am using Scrapy 1.5.1


for red_paragraph in response.xpath('//p[re:test(text(), "\([A-Z]{3,}\)"]')
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing colon on that line. I have not tested this code myself.

Comment: can you please send me again

Comment: Thank you  Gallaecio, You are really a intelligent programmer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you use xpath 2.0, you can use regex in selector like `//p[matches(text(),'[\w\s]+\([\w+]\)','i')]`. 
Or try to iterate like this (not exact code, just example):

```
for sel in response.css('p'):
    txt = sel.css('::text').get()
    if not txt or not re.match('[\w\s]+\([\w+]\)', txt):
         continue
    # do what you need with selector sel
```

Comment: From html you can see that they don't have parent block with which you can unite them. So you can process all `p` blocks, collecting them in internal array. Like: iterate by `p`; if you meet block that fits your regex for header then start collecting selectors or extracted text; next time you meet the same block, you finish with previous and start new one.

Comment: can you generate a separator by using there space https://prnt.sc/lokim0

Comment: No, have no idea how to use `&nbsp;` for selection. Maybe you can use `if not txt.strip():` as starting flag for block collection, but I don't think that it is reliable way for crawling.

Comment: As a side note: Scrapy does not support XPath 2.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920609/scrapy-and-xpath-function-matches-syntax but it does support an extension, “re”, so using re:test() in place of matches() is possible. That said, the suggested non-XPath approach is the way to go.